# Tensor contraction in matrix product state

Tags: hilbert-space, tensor-calculus, notation, tensor-network

From [Matrix product state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_product_state), the matrix product can be written as

$$
|\Psi\rangle = \sum_{\{s\}} \operatorname{Tr}\left[A_1^{(s_1)} A_2^{(s_2)} \cdots A_N^{(s_N)}\right] |s_1 s_2 \ldots s_N\rangle,
$$

The summation of $s$ is over the superscripts. Typically, tensor contractions happen between upper and lower indices (though they don't have to).

In https://tensornetwork.org/mps/

$$T^{s_1 s_2 \cdots s_6} = \sum_{\{ \alpha \}} A^{s_1}_{\alpha_1} A^{s_2}_{\alpha_1  \alpha_2 } \cdots A^{s_5}_{\alpha_4  \alpha_5 }  A^{s_6}_{\alpha_5 } , $$
the contraction of $\alpha$ is over lower indices.

My question is, is there any underlying principle to let the contraction of indices in the matrix product state happen at upper or lower indices, not in between?

Comment: If you write the ket as $|s_1s_2\cdots s_N\rangle=e_{s_1}\otimes e_{s_2}\otimes\cdots\otimes e_{s_N}$, then everything works out.

Comment: Thanks...  btw, in other formulation of MPS, https://tensornetwork.org/mps/,  equation (3), the summations are over lower indices $\{ \alpha \}$, how to understand the summation there? (and https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.2164.pdf, eq (25) ~ (26) seem common in many places)

Comment: People in the MPS community don't really make a difference between upper and lower indices (it's just a Euclidean metric). Especially for this $\alpha$-index since it's in general just seen as a label.

Comment: Yeah, when people in the tensor network community say "tensor", they usually just mean "multidimensional array", rather than anything which transforms like a tensor in GR, or has any difference between up and down indices.